# Universal Image Loader, More efficient downloading with less data. How?

Tags: java, android, asp.net, image, universal-image-loader

I'have a ASP.NET Webservice and also a site which accepts image uploading. I retrive this pictures in android client using universal image loader. Everything works okay, but the problem is that loading is not that fast. Well on wifi is fast but what it bothers me that data consumption is too big. So if i have 10 images on my server, and each image has around 500kb , that means that for 10 images i spend 5Mb of data only on my GridView.

So my question is:

Is it possible to show only sample image,  and not the "real thing". So instead of 500kb, image should have around 50kb or something ( thumbnail ). Is this possible to do on Android or do I need to have little images saved on my server and retrieved from there? The problem is that some images could be 1 or 2Mb big, and therefore we have a really big problem.

If is it possible to do with Universal Image Loader, i would appriciate some help :)

Answer (score 1):

The option that I have used before is to have a function where you can pass the image path as well as a 'quality' parameter. The 'quality' parameter is up to you, but my system reduced the dimensions of the image, as well as a few other minor tweaks. The function will then check to see if that image exists already, and if not it will create it locally. You can always write a script to clean up the local images after a certain amount of time has passed.

Since most images are already compressed depending on the type, your best option would be to resize them using smaller dimensions. You can always stretch the smaller image to fit whatever display you are using, so users shouldn't be able to tell much of a difference. You could also provide an option to view the higher quality image (or possibly sell it as an upgrade).